# How do I split on a "." but only if there are non-numbers following it?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, split

I want to split a line by a space, or a `"."` separating a number in front of it and a non-number behind it. I want to split like:

```
"10.ABC DEF GHI" # => ["10", "ABC", "DEF", "GHI"]
"10.00 DEF GHI" #=> ["10.00", "DEF", "GHI"]
```

I have

```
words = line.strip.split(/(?<=\d)\.|[[:space:]]+/)
```

But I discovered this doesn't quite do what I want. Although it will split the line:

```
line = "10.ABC DEF GHI"
words = line.strip.split(/(?<=\d)\.|[[:space:]]+/) # => ["10", "ABC", "DEF", "GHI"]
```

It will also incorrectly split

```
line = "10.00 DEF GHI"
line.strip.split(/(?<=\d)\.|[[:space:]]+/) # => ["10", "00", "DEF", "GHI"]
```

How do I correct my regular expression to only split on the dot if there are non-numbers following the `"."`?

Comment: Just curious, where are all your questions coming from? It's not easy to come up with one Ruby question every day.

Comment: ...and there's been a steady improvement in the questions. Keep it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!\d)` after `\.`:

```
/(?<=\d)\.(?!\d)|[[:space:]]+/
          ^^^^^^
```

It will fail the match if the `.` is followed with a digit.

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/9UUqbM61H9).

Comment: You regex enforces "...not followed by a number", but the OP wants "...and a non-number behind it", which is slightly different (though the OP may actually want "not followed"). Maybe give regexes for both interpretations.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I do not think it is necessary, see *I want to split a line by a space, or a "." separating a number in front of it and a non-number behind it.* It means there must be a digit before the dot (`(?<=\d)`) and there cannot be a digit after it (`(?!\d)`).

Comment: I don't see how "...and a non-number behind it" could mean anything other than that it must be followed by a character that is not a number. "Nothing" is not a "non-number". It would be like concluding that "The stalker was following a non-male" could mean the stalker wasn't following anybody. For your interpretation one would say "...and not followed by a number" (though "digit" would be better).

Comment: There is a difference between "must be followed by a character that is not a number" and "must not be followed by a number". The latter (my interpretation) approach will also split a string at the dot that is at the string end.